# Do I need to restart my system after setting JAVA in system environment's path variable?

Tags: java, java-home

I did the following steps but java does not seem to be working for me, do I need to restart my system if yes then why?

```
1. Right click My Computer->Advence Option->Environment Varibles->System Variables 
    2. variable : Path->Edit
    3. Copy your jdk bin directory i.e.C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin
    4. Paste it after putting a semi-colon(;) in value section
```

i am getting below error while running java in cmd

```
C:\Users\User>java -version
Error: opening registry key 'Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment'
Error: could not find java.dll
Error: Could not find Java SE Runtime Environment.
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with it? You do need to restart any processes that would be referencing your variable (i.e. cmd).

Comment: No need to restart your computer, but need to restart your shell ;)

Comment: @Nizil what is a shell?

Comment: @Adrian Well, strictly speaking it's an interface to the kernel (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_(computing)#Unix-like_systems)), but it's often used as an umbrella term that refers to the command line interpreter or even the terminal.

Comment: Same here, not typical java person (did most of my java using Blaze at Google), so no actual experience with gradle/etc. But on my Windows machine I had to go to my c:\Users\<user>\.gradle folder and delete everything before running again (to compile some project I was learning something else from it). Seems like it caches it really baddly :)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

No, but you will need to close and recreate any `cmd` windows, running java programs, or the like.

To check it's correct, open a new `cmd` window and type `set` -> review the information for `PATH` and `JAVA_HOME`.

Comment: i have restarted windows cmd and it gives error like below. 
C:\Users\User>java
Error: opening registry key 'Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment'
Error: could not find java.dll
Error: Could not find Java SE Runtime Environment.

Comment: do i need to set JAVA_HOME also

Comment: Yes, they should definitely be in sync.

Answer (score 5):

You should set two things:

1. JAVA_HOME
2. PATH

The first lies under the "User variables for [your user name]" section. Add the JAVA_HOME variable and set it to where your jdk is installed. i.e. C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\

The second lies under the "System variables" section. You should find the "path" variable, and edit it. Then, append ";%JAVA_HOME%\bin" (minus the quotes) to the end of the path variable.

After you have done this, save the variables and close that window clicking the "ok" button. Close down all instances of the command prompt (and any IDE you may be developing with such as Eclipse or NetBeans), and reopen one command prompt. Then, if you would like to test whether or not your changes worked and are in effect, try the following:

```
echo %JAVA_HOME%
```

This should output where you set your java home variable to.

```
echo %PATH%
```

At the end of what is output, you should see your java home\bin addition to the path variable

```
java -version
```

If you can run this command from the command line, it means that your environment was set up correctly and java is now in your path.

Comment: i am getting below error
C:\Users\User>java -version
Error: opening registry key 'Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment'
Error: could not find java.dll
Error: Could not find Java SE Runtime Environment.

Comment: This appears to be an issue with when you installed the JDK, this isn't a pathing issue. My suggestion would be to completely uninstall the JDK and JRE (as well as deleting the folders they resided in) and try reinstalling. Then repeat the process above in my answer.

Comment: You should also make sure you remove any java.exe, javaw.exe and javaws.exe from your Windows\System32 folder and if you have an x64 system (Win 7 64 bits) also do the same under Windows\SysWOW64.

Answer (score 4):

Not necessary. Quit and Open the command prompt again (if any) that runs the java process and type `java -version` to check if it installed successfully.

If you are using mac, `source ~/.bashrc` or `source ~/.zshrc` should refresh your environmental variable. No need to re-start the terminal even.

Answer (score 3):

No, you don't need to restart your system.
However, you have to restart your command prompt application to update the changes done on Environment variables.

Answer (score 1):

NO.
You don't need to restart the system, but just the application like `cmd` or any IDE you are using for java development (i.e Eclipse) need to restart.

And to confirm that the java path is set that you have mentioned in JAVA_HOME environment variable, you can open `cmd` and you can check with commands `echo %JAVA_HOME%` or `echo %PATH%`.

Answer (score 0):

I reinstall the `JDK` and set the `JAVA_HOME` and `PATH` variable again. now it's working.

Answer (score 0):

In my case under user variable section(for particularuser) JAVA_HOME set to jre not jdk path . I change it to JDK path , It worked for me

Answer (score 0):

yes need to restart cmd prompt after env variable change