# wamp - xdebug configuration is not getting saved

Tags: php, phpstorm, wamp, xdebug

This is my xdebug configuration in my php.ini

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension="C:\wamp64\bin\php\php5.6.35\zend_ext\php_xdebug-2.5.5-5.6-vc11-x86_64.dll"
xdebug.remote_log = C:\wamp64\logs\xdebug.log
xdebug.idekey = PHPSTORM
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"
xdebug.remote_autostart = on
xdebug.remote_start = on
xdebug.remote_enable = on
xdebug.remote_connect_back = on
```

it is at the very bottom of the file.
As you can see, I have set the `xdebug.idekey` to `PHPSTORM`, but `phpinfo()` shows that the value is not set, what am I doing wrong?

I also set the idekey through PhpStorm, but why is there `no value` entry in phpinfo() at the bottom? The top one is filled ?!

[image]

Comment: Have you : Restart your server ? / Have you an environment variable DBGP_IDEKEY ?

Comment: Yes, I restarted the apache server after it. No the env var DBGP_IDEKEY  does not exist. I looked it up by starting the cmd and executed `set`

Comment: https://xdebug.org/docs/remote from the doc it should be.

Comment: Did you have PHPSTORM setted in support section before my answer ? Or just right after the environment variable ?

Comment: I set it before your answer, so Im not sure either which action changed it. The question is, why is the `xdebug.idekey` value set to `no value` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT** from comments and @Black's answer this is the answer :

WAMP use 3 PHP.ini files :

- Apache's file : `wamp\bin\apache\apache[version]\bin\php.ini`
- PHP's file : `wamp\bin\php\php[version]\php.ini`
- Third file : `wamp\bin\php\php[version]\phpForApache.ini`

First two files are usefull, apache's file is used for HTTP calls, PHP's one for CGI/CLI. The third one is used when your WAMP has 2 PHP's version, WAMP use it for saving the current config and then create a new PHP.ini file for the new version. This happens during the switch of PHP's version.

In the Xdebug's case, indeed it was the apache's file that matter. It's a common issue when the phpinfo don't show any modifications.

If you have the same configuration between those two files, you also can make a symlink from PHP's file to apache one. This will save a lot of headache.

---

**UNLUCKY TRIES**
Depends on your request, you may want to configure your server with differents things.

You tried to use Xdebug as remote, then your IDEKEY should be SET as environment variable named : `DBGP_IDEKEY`

Here's the doc :

> **xdebug.idekey**
>
> Type: string, Default value: *complex* Controls which IDE Key Xdebug
>   should pass on to the DBGp debugger handler. The default is based on
>   environment settings. First the environment setting DBGP_IDEKEY is
>   consulted, then USER and as last USERNAME. *The default is set to the
>   first environment variable that is found. If none could be found the
>   setting has as default ''. If this setting is set, it always overrides
>   the environment variables.*

You may be concerned by conditions that I pointed out with italic text

as linked in comment, take a look at the full [documentation](https://xdebug.org/docs/remote)

I remember that WAMP use Xdebug as an Thread safe extension, you should try to 
replace

`zend_extension="C:\wamp64\bin\php\php5.6.35\zend_ext\php_xdebug-2.5.5-5.6-vc11-x86_64.dll"`

by

```
zend_extension_ts="C:\wamp64\bin\php\php5.6.35\zend_ext\php_xdebug-2.5.5-5.6-vc11-x86_64.dll"
```

And check if you have download a correct version of Xdebug (Thread Safe)

Then restart wamp and see if something has changed.

**EDIT :** You have an issue with your PHP.ini, you're not modifying the right one. I succeeded on mine with this :

```
; XDEBUG Extension zend_extension = "C:\wamp\bin\php\php7.0.4\zend_ext\php_xdebug-2.4.0-7.0-vc14-x86_64.dll" ; 

[xdebug] 
xdebug.remote_enable=1 
xdebug.idekey = "PHPSTORM" 
xdebug.remote_autostart= on 
xdebug.remote_connect_back= 1 
xdebug.remote_host="127.0.0.1" 
xdebug.remote_port=9000 
xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp" 
xdebug.remote_mode=req 
xdebug.profiler_enable = 0 
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "c:/wamp/tmp/" 
xdebug.collect_params = On 
xdebug.show_local_vars = On`
```

[image: here is what i got]

Comment: Thanks! But it made no difference.

Comment: Did you restart cmd tools ? see : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24307782/do-i-need-to-restart-my-system-after-setting-java-in-system-environments-path-v

Comment: I successfully set the env var now via the windows GUI instead of using the cmd. I also updated my question with a screenshot to make it clearer what I mean.

Comment: Ok can you take a look at this wizard from xdebug ? https://xdebug.org/wizard.php

Comment: I replaced `zend_extension` with `zend_extension_ts` and restarted apache, but it made no difference.

Comment: Ok, if you remove all your configuration and restart, is Xdebug still available ? My first suspicion now is that your PHP.ini is ignored or anything like this

Comment: Nice idea. It seems like my configuration does not do anything, xdebug is still available after removing it and restarting apache. Hmm.

Comment: Edited my answer with my own tests confirming that you're edit the wrong PHP.ini file for me

Comment: I figured out, that replacing `zend_extension` with `zend_extension_ts` and removing the config as whole did not changed anything in phpinfo, but I noticed that my IDE (phpstorm) says that no debugger is installed. I had to add my config again to make it work.

I will try to alter the other php.ini's later.

Comment: @black Final edit done, thanks for rep. I hope my answer is helpfull now.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why it was not saved is that on `wamp` you have to store your config in `C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache_VERSION\bin\php.ini` instead of `C:\wamp64\bin\php\php_VERSION\php.ini`.

I searched my whole `wamp/bin/php` folder for the occurence of the string `xdebug` by using Notepad++, thats how I found it out.