# Unable to change the env variable in Windows without reboot

Tags: java, path, environment-variables

I am using windows with Java 10 and Java 8 installed. I have changed the env variable to point to java 8 but it is not getting reflected in system `java --version`.It is showing java 10.0.1.

I can see the correct values of env variables JAVA_HOME and PATH pointing to jdk 1.8 bin in cmd after restarting it. 
`echo %JAVA_HOME%\bin`.
`echo %PATH%`

I have checked most of the already answered questions and tried that but it is still showing java 10. like: 
[Do I need to restart my system after setting JAVA in system environment's path variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24307782/do-i-need-to-restart-my-system-after-setting-java-in-system-environments-path-v)

Answer (score 0):

You used two - marks. Try with one: `java -version`

in order to use java8 , bring the jdk1.80pointer to the top.