# Gradle wrapper get wrong Java version in Android project on Windows

Tags: java, android, gradle

I am using gradle within an Android project on Windows.

When I execute `./gradlew -version` within my project path, error is shown as `Could not determine java version from '12'.`

I did have **both Java 8 and 12 installed** on my machine but my `JAVA_HOME` variable is set to jdk1.8 path, the JDK location in Android Studio is also set to jdk1.8. as show below. If I call `java -version` from cmd I could also get version 1.8 instead of version 12.

[image: JDK location setup in Android Studio]

So why does gradle get a wrong version of Java? Is there any other configuration that might lead to this result?

Gradle version is 4.1 but I prefer not to update it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this.

Please change your JAVA path (from jdk1.8 to jdk12) in your computer from properties.

**Go to Computer Properties -> Advanced System setting -> Environment variable -> Edit Path - C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.1\bin**

Then restart your PC and android studio and check jdk location in android studio.

Comment: thank you, I did solve if after a [restart](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55757398/4476501). Environmental variable has already been modifiyied before. But a restart is needed to let it work.

Comment: @SummerSun : yes restart is needed. Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to uninstall Java 12 from my machine, and gradle report JAVA_HOME = JAVA_12_DIR is empty, which means JAVA_HOME is still not updated somehow.

So I restart the machine, and the Java version is correctly specified now.

The reason is probably that I did not shut all my cmd and running java programs down. So JAVA_HOME is not properly updated. Although in a new cmd window, the newly updated JAVA_HOME can be found.

---

Please refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24307815/4476501) for environmental variable updating detail.

> No, but you will need to close and recreate any cmd windows, running java programs, or the like.
>
> To check it's correct, open a new cmd window and type set -> review the information for PATH and JAVA_HOME.